# Inconsistent Modulus (=MOD()) Behavior in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm running into some confusing behavior in an excel spreadsheet. Two columns, which we'll call A and B. A contains a "time decimal" such as 0.15 or 0.30 (fifteen or thirty minutes). I need to convert this to "normal decimal," such as 0.25 or 0.5. The values from this come from other columns in the table.

Before I can do my conversion, I need to find whether the time should be rounded to the quarter hour. I thought I'd use =MOD() to check whether the "time decimal" * 100 is evenly divisible by 15.

BUT: I'm getting inconsistent results. In Column A I have the "time decimal" and in column B I have the formula:

```
=MOD(A1*100,15)
```

In the following screenshot, I would expect it to give 0 in both rows, but it is not:
[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

As far as I can tell, the data in A1 and A2 is identical. All of the four visible cells are of Type "Number."

Is there something going on behind the scenes that I don't know about? Is there a way I can force the correct behavior?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likeliest reason is that the first one is not exactly 0.30, but 0.299999 for example. That would make the result of `MOD(xx*100,15)` 14.99999, which shows as 15.00 if you only show 2 decimals.

Comment: I thought of that, but increasing the decimal place returns expected results: 0.30000000000 etc.

Comment: In addition A1 * 100 / 15 = 2.0000000

Comment: @BPMJ try to add a formula: `=A1=0.3` and check that it returns true.

Comment: @BPMJ Alternatively, replace your existing formula with `=MOD(ROUND(A1*100,0),15)` and see if you get the same result.

Comment: interestingly enough =A1=0.3 returned true. Rounding the value, produced the correct results.. as did taking an =INT(A1*100). To my programmer brain, getting the INT value makes sense :-)